# HG Push Failed; Permission denied .hg/store/lock

Tags: mercurial, ubuntu

I have been trying to setup a mercurial repository on my server so that my team can work from theirs. I am running Ubuntu server 10.4 and I did the install of mercurial using apt-get. Now this all went smoothly.

I init a dir with hg just fine, I setup the hgrc as follows:

```
[web]
push_ssl = False
allow_push = *

[trusted]
users = *
groups=
```

then I run `hg serve`. The server begins listening. I can clone this repository to another computer but when I try and push my changes i get the error:

```
C:\Users\UserName\Project1>hg push http://MyInternalIP:8000
pushing to http://MyInternalIP:8000
searching for changes
abort: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

On the server side I get the following error:

```
LockUnavailable: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/UserName/projects/Project1/.hg/store/lock'
```

If anyone has a solution to how to fix this that would be amazing. I have googled and found people with similar issues and they say that it may have something to do with the web user not having permissions but I am new to all of this and none of them give solutions on how to fix the issue. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 10):

You must allow write access to the repository directories to the user running the Mercurial server process. I.e the user account running `hg serve` must be able to write to `/home/UserName/projects/Project1/`

BTW can you provide more details as to what command line you used to clone the repository?

Comment: why not just chown to the user running hg serve, and chmod -R 644 Project1?

Comment: If you're running on apache2, the default user:group is www-data:www-data

Answer (score 3):

In my case with mercurial repository on redmine

> HTTP Error: 500 (Permission denied)

Run

```
chown -R www-data /path/to/repos
```

on the server, it worked for me.

([Fuente](https://thedevignpath.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/mercurial-tips/))